# How to remove empty space between player and ground in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am learning Phaser 3 by creating a small platform game, everything works as I want, but when the player loads there is some space between him and the ground, what is causing this and how can I fix it? I want him to be standing on the ground without any space between, here is a picture:

https://ibb.co/Px65JMR

and here is my js code:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/world/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'assets/world/ground.png');
    this.load.image('platform', 'assets/world/platform.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/characters/player.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    ground = this.physics.add.staticGroup();


    platforms.create(600, 400, 'platform');
    platforms.create(50, 250, 'platform');
    platforms.create(750, 220, 'platform');
    ground.create(500, 550, 'ground')


    // Creating the player
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 350, 'player');

    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    player.body.setGravityY(300)
    this.physics.add.collider(player, ground);

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'turn',
        frames: [{ key: 'player', frame: 4 }],
        frameRate: 20
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });

}

function update() {
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();


    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);

        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(160);

        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);

        player.anims.play('turn');
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
        player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/characters/player.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
```

Did you make sure that the frameHeight of the sprite is 48 and not 32x32?

Also, I'd recommend you to add **debug=true**
to your configuration:

```
    arcade: {
      debug: true,
      gravity: { y: 300 }
    }
```

By doing so, each object will be marked by a purple outline, I bet you will figure it out in no time.

Comment: Thank! The debug mode is very helpful indeed, where can I set the height? I see thanks to the debug mode that my asset has added height to it causing this issue but I don't know how to change it

Comment: It depends which asset need to be rescaled

Comment: the 'ground' one

Comment: Look at my new answer. Hope it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution 1:

try to reduce the second param here:

```
ground.create(500, 550, 'ground')
```

to - lets say- 450.

possible solution 2:

```
ground.create(500, 550, 'ground').setSize(500,500, true);
ground.refresh();
```